# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: Please provide data which shares the same first dimension. When training a multiple inputs CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, valueerror

I am training a multiple inputs CNN, with different numbers of images in each imputs.
The dimension of Input A is (23, 500, 500, 3)
The dimension of input B is (43, 500, 500, 3)

But I got the ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 23, 43
y sizes: 66
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.

The code is as follow:

```
input_A = Input(shape=(500, 500, 3), name='input_A')

hidden_A0=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=7, padding='SAME')(input_A)

MaxPool_A1=keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(hidden_A0)

hidden_A1=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='SAME')(MaxPool_A1)

hidden_A2=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='SAME')(hidden_A1)

MaxPool_A2=keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(hidden_A2)

hidden_A3=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',padding='SAME')(MaxPool_A2)

hidden_A4=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',padding='SAME')(hidden_A3)

MaxPool_A3=keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(hidden_A4)

output_A =keras.layers.Dense(units=126, activation='relu',name='hidden_total_A1')(MaxPool_A3)

model_A=keras.Model(inputs=input_A, outputs=output_A)



input_B = Input(shape=(700, 500, 3), name='input_B')

hidden_B0=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=7, padding='SAME')(input_B)

MaxPool_B1=keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(hidden_B0)

hidden_B1=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='SAME')(MaxPool_B1)

hidden_B2=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='SAME')(hidden_B1)

MaxPool_B2=keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(hidden_B2)

output_B=keras.layers.Dense(units=126, activation='relu',name='hidden_total_B1')(MaxPool_B2)

model_B=keras.Model(inputs=input_B, outputs=output_B)



conbined=keras.layers.concatenate([model_A.output, model_B.output])
conbined=Flatten()(combined)

output=keras.layers.Dense(units=4, activation='softmax')(combined)
model=keras.Model(inputs=[model_A.input, model_B.input], outputs=[output])]


model.compile(loss=["sparse_categorical_crossentropy","sparse_categorical_crossentropy"], optimizer="sgd", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x=[X1,X2],y=y_tensor, epochs=10, batch_size=10)
```

X1 is Input A

X2 is input B

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The error is very clear. What do you intend to happen here?

Comment: My problem is how can I fix that? Could you explain that more specifically? Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62951778/14290681) answer your question?